# Cakephp: find in a controller using "like" inside an array of possible values

Tags: sql, cakephp, find, sql-like

The main idea of this post is that I need to combine search inside an array via "like" without doing a fetch.

In the following code I extract the zones (part of postal code) depending on session ID:

```
 $sess_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
 $this->loadModel('Zone', 2);
 $MyZones = $this->Zone->find('list', array('recursive' => -1, 'conditions' => array('Zone.user_id' => $sess_id['id']), 'fields' => array('Zone.zone')));
 $this->set('MyZones', $MyZones);

 print_r($MyZones);  
//output : $MyZone = Array ( [1] => AB [2] => AL [3] => B1 )
```

Now that I have my array I want to look for persons who live in this zone (example his postalcode can be AB526PQ so he lives in the administrator zone)

```
 $this->loadModel('Person', 2);
 $num_persons = $this->Person->find('count', array('recursive' => -1, 'conditions' => array('Person.pc LIKE' => '%' . $MyZones)));


 $this->set('num_persons', $num_persons);
```

I got the following error :

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP\Controller\ZonesController.php]
```

This is the generated sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `tn`.`personnes` AS `Personne` WHERE `Personne`.`pc` LIKE '%Array'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to break your condition from

```
$conditions = array('Person.pc LIKE' => '%' . $MyZones);
```

to

```
foreach($MyZones as $MyZone) {
     $conditions[] = array('Person.pc LIKE' => '%' . $MyZone);
}
```

Comment: I am looking for an alternative without foreach (fetch) if possible like what is used via "IN". sample:

`'NOT' => array(
         array('Company.status' => array('inactive', 'suspended'))
 )`
 We processed here an array of values, same as what I need but without the like operator.

Comment: @Shinigami you should have designed database accordingly for that

Comment: No need for a special design to the database for statistical purpose only (find("count")). Any way thank you that served me a lot. I have just found another possibilities which are regex and rlike. I will try to study and implement them otherwise, I'll use this alternative. Do you have any idea?. thank you.